# Throwing error 'Cannot find the symbol variable' after updating Android studio from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-debug

I have updated my Android Studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1. After updating, If I add code to the project, it is showing 'Cannot find symbol variable' error for instantiation.

And also showing 'CompileDebugJavawithJavac' error and 'minimum gradle version required 4.4, present version is 4.1'.

I don't know what went wrong. But, my app worked fine with 3.0.1. What could be the possible solution.

Comment: Cannot find what symbol? The actual error is your code not compiling please show a [mcve], and your gradle build output

Comment: It is showing minimum gradle version required 4.4, present version is 4.1'. and then re-import your project.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue after upgrading to gradle 3.1.0. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: Yes. I found the solution. What went wrong in your case...??? Throwing error 'Cannot find the symbol variable'...??? @Amit

Comment: yes, not for all but for few kotlin specific symbols in java file. e.g - Unit, @Nullable etc. It used to work on 3.0.1

Comment: In my case, when I upgraded, it created additional layout for one xml file. and it is accessing that additional file. check your xml files in layout, if any duplicates created. @Amit

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Gradle version from 4.1 to 4.4 (which is the minimum required by AndroidStudio 3.1)

Go to your project's `build.gradle` file, and check that you have your gradle plugin updated to the version 3.1.0:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    ...
}
```

After this, go to your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and check that you have the required gradle version (i.e. 4.4)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Then, perform a full `clean` and `rebuild`.
Your code should compile now and stop showing the 'Cannot find symbol variable' error.